# Как вытащить сущность, которая FetchType.LAZY?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, spring-jpa, spring-data-jpa

Имею сущность `User` и сущность `Thing`.

Сущность `Thing` ссылается на `User` с отношением ManyToOne:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
@NotNull
private User user;
```

Мне надо вытащить `Thing` вместе с `User`, к которому он относится, причём `User` должен вытаскиваться как реальный объект, а не обёртка. Как это сделать?

Comment: Вы делаете запрос на from Thing, и у Вас будет thing.user подгружен при первом же обращении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы вытащить сущность, которая отмечена `FetchType.Lazy`, необходимо использовать метод `Hibernate.unproxy()`, который возвращает реальную сущность, без обёртки. Разумеется, этот метод необходимо вызывать в транзакции.

Конкретно для моего примера это выглядело бы так:

```
@Transactional
public void getWithUser(int id) {
    Thing thing = repository.findById(id);
    thing.setUser(Hibernate.unproxy(thing.getUser()));
    return thing;
}
```